# Undefined constant after switch from PHP 7.0 to 7.2

Tags: php, wordpress

my website hoster will soon switch all accounts from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2. So I installed a clone of my current WordPress installation in order to test it with PHP 7.2. When I have PHP 7.0 activated then everything works fine. But when I'm switching to PHP 7.2 I'm getting a weird error message from one of the plugins.

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant TABBER_TABS_DIR - assumed 'TABBER_TABS_DIR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/xeccbike/public_html/testing/wp-content/plugins/tabber-tabs-widget/tabber-tabs.php on line 31

30: / Set constant path to the plugin directory.
31: define( TABBER_TABS_DIR, plugins_url('tabber-tabs-widget/'));
32: 
33: // Load Language
34: load_plugin_textdomain('tabber-tabs-widget', false, TABBER_TABS_DIR . 'language');
```

Does anyone have an idea what that could be? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

AJ

Answer (score 3):

I had that too. I just put the constant in single quotes  as suggested by the warning message (in your case that would be `define( 'TABBER_TABS_DIR', plugins_url('tabber-tabs-widget/'));` on line 31), which solved it.

Comment: Note reference in manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php first argument expects a string.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at this code snippet:

```
$string = test;

if ($string == 'test') {

    echo "This is test string";

}
```

Obviously you can see unquoted string test here. In PHP 7.1 output of the script would be:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' in ...
This is test string
```

but in PHP 7.2 the output would be:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in ...
This is test string
```

As you see it’s not a big change (Notice was changed into Warning), however in PHP 8 it will probably cause an error.

The main cause of this change is not stopping just support for unquoted string but to avoid serious problems when you typo some PHP keywords.

I suggest I suggest reading [this article](http://devpark.pl/what-changed-in-php-7-2/?lang=en). Maybe useful